# Auto-filling formulas with cross-referencing and calculation method

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-word

I am working on a project that will automatically perform a long list of self- cross-referencing calculations.
Is there an easy and elegant way to:

1. Display the formula to be calculated
2. Retrieve values from an excel table imbedded into a word file and replace the variables with the corresponding value.
3. Calculate the equation and have it be referenceable by another excel file

[image: illustration]

I’ve tried to make an illustration to better explain what I’m looking for.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Just off the top of my head, the answer to your question - "easy and elegant way" - is no, no easy way. Probably can be done by *coding*, with possible exception of 3), "referencing" by another Excel file - depending on exactly what you mean. But as it stands, this topic is "too broad" for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is only offered as a possible help, not as a definitive answer, but I needed to create some questions involving BODMAS ie order of precedence and came up with this.

Excel is set to display formulae - not results, sadly the formula in column F has to be updated to match the operators used in B and D... Did try indirect() but could not get it to work for some reason - and getting 30 questions produced was more important...

The cells F1:F4 are copied, then paste.special values into cells G1:G4

[image]